# Query an xml query not working with xmlns tags

Tags: xml, t-sql

I want to select certain rows that have a certain xml field in them. I know my problem is with the namespaces, but I can't seem to get them ironed out correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c23b3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to your query and namespase alias (like `ns1`) to XPATH-request

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('bb_appfx_table' as ns1)
select 
    ID as VALUE, 
    NAME as LABEL,
    TABLESPECXML
from 
    T1
where
    TABLESPECXML.exist('/ns1:TableSpec/ns1:Fields[ns1:ForeignKeyField[@Name="USR_TRANSACTIONPROCESSORID"]]') = 1
order by 
    NAME
```

Comment: Thanks man! I had tried something like that, but didn't put the ns1 on the ForeignKeyField! Doh!